# Visual Studio is throwing a "wrong" compile time exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

In order to deploy my project in Mono, I've downgraded it to .Net 4.0 as I've done with the library which I'm referencing (CommonUtils). However, I'm still getting the following exception:

> The primary reference "CommonUtils" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

What I've tried to resolve the issue:

- I've re-installed all Nuget packages in both projects
- I've multiple times tried to clean the projects / solutions, delete all bin/obj folder an rebuild everything
- I've changed the name of the assembly in order to be sure nothing is cached

None of this helped.

Both projects are set to be compiled as .Net 4.0. The reference is by copying the compiled assembly *CommonUtils* into an "ExternalLibraries"-folder, since this DLL is also used in other projects.

Right-click on Newtonsoft.Json.dll - which is moved to the `bin` folder together with *CommonUtils* - shows in Details/File description: `Json.NET .NET 4.0`

I am pretty sure that I have everything correct for .net 4.0 and Visual Studio also lets me add the library and supports me with auto-completion, just the compiling throws the mentioned  warning. As a result of the warning, suddenly I get exceptions that none of the types referenced from *CommonUtils* exists

> The type of namespace name 'CommonUtils' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What else can I try to make this work?

PS: I had a similar problem few years ago, where an old assembly was used for compiling, and "solved" it by literally setting up windows and visual studio from scratch, but I just don't feel like doing it this time.

**Update:**

It works on another computer: I've taken the folder structure via USB Stick to another computer with the same OS (Windows 8.1) and the same Visual Studio 2013 - as far as I can tell, both computers should have all the updates installed - and there it works.

Taking the USB Stick with the successfully compiled project back to my PC - I'm still getting the same errors.

(I understand, this means that both computers can't possibly have everything the same installed, but I wouldn't know how to find the difference, maybe some hint with what can be wrong this way?)

---

**Update 2:**

Process explorer didn't help too much, but when I compiled everything with diagnostic log, I think I got the key hint:

```
...
5>  Unified primary reference "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". (TaskId:158)
5>      Using this version instead of original version "4.5.0.0" in "C:\<SolutionFolder>\packages\WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "Web.config". (TaskId:158)
5>      Using this version instead of original version "4.5.0.0" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "Web.config". (TaskId:158)
5>      Using this version instead of original version "4.5.0.0" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "Web.config". (TaskId:158)
5>      Resolved file path is "C:\<SolutionFolder>\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll". (TaskId:158)
5>      Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:158)
5>      Found related file "C:\<SolutionFolder>\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.xml". (TaskId:158)
5>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319". (TaskId:158)
...
```

However, I get the exact same message also on the other computer where the build is working.

Additionally both computers show this line in the beginning:

```
Skipping NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3 since it is already installed.
```

What does `installed` mean in this context? that NuGet downloaded it? or is it somewhere in the GAC, but I couldn't find it? (see comments)

And on the machine, where the compilation works, I get additionally this output:

```
1>  Dependency "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". (TaskId:17)
1>      Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll". (TaskId:17)
1>      Reference found at search path location "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}". (TaskId:17)
1>          For SearchPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies". (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.exe", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:17)
1>          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}". (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Newtonsoft.Json.exe", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:17)
1>          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}". (TaskId:17)
1>          Considered AssemblyFoldersEx locations. (TaskId:17)
1>      Required by "CommonUtils". (TaskId:17)
1>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319". (TaskId:17)
```

But I don't see it on my computer, where the compilation fails

**Final Update:**

I gave up and reinstalled my whole system - it works now, however it doesn't answer the question where the wrong Newtonsoft.Json.dll came from and why it didn't show up in the GAC, I can finally again work on that project.

I'm actually quite disappointed, that it can't be as easy as in maven, where you can just delete one folder in order to make maven redownload all the libraries.

I have an image of the broken system on a VHD, so if anyone else comes up with a great solution, I can try it out in the VM.

Comment: Try searching all files in your solution for the string "4.5.0.0".

Comment: Also, check the "Use specific version" flag for `CommonUtils`. Maybe it's set to "Yes" and forcing you to use a higher version than what you want.

Comment: You'll need to focus on the *indirect* dependency.  CommonUtils has a reference to another assembly and *that* assembly was built with the new version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll.  This is not directly visible from VS, you can see it by running ildasm.exe on the direct dependencies.

Comment: Check if someone had brilliant idea to install Newtonsoft.Json to GAC...

Comment: Looks like you have a later version of Newtonsoft on _this_ computer and not on _that_ computer. You might have to uninstall all traces of Newtonsoft first, then reinstall just the older version.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - no, `gacutil -l` didn't show anything even remotely similar to Newtonsof.Json. Unless there are multiple different GACs, it shouldn't be in one. @david.pfx - I never installed it in any form, and nobody else either, it isn't in the gac - so how can I uninstall it?

Comment: @david.pfx - ok, I've searched my entire drive for `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and have removed all files from temporary folders and AppData, ... The other files I found seemed the same as on the functioning second computer in terms of location and version.

Comment: Try using a tool like ProcessExplorer to see where your program is loading its DLL from.

Comment: @zahorak: Search me. No, that wouldn't help -- keep looking -- there is a reference in there somewhere.

Comment: @Vache I've tried your idea, but Visual Studio was always referencing the correct Newtonsoft.Json.dll and I couldn't get any references from the compilers, as they failed too fast. But this brought me to the idea to set the build output to diagnostics in Visual Studio - see the question update for the results

Comment: Azure VS Tools 2.3 breaking MSBuild for web projects https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/850425/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the solution was to delete the `Newtonsoft.json.dll` located in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.3\ref`

This is described as a workaround in this [Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/850425/).

Edit: Original bug report removed, possible new/related/same issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816985

Comment: In my case it was I had to search for newtonsoft.json.dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.8\ and then moved them to recycle. There were three instances. Now, it works!

Comment: The link to the Connect bug indicated in this answer is presently broken. I believe that issue in question is #816985 and can be seen here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816985. The issue is actually a bug in VS.NET whereby it incorrectly resolves the the Newtonsoft dependency.

Comment: I would look into any copy under the ProgramFiles folder. See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816725/visual-studio-referencing-dll-in-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-visual-studio-12-0-blend-directory-incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I gave up and reinstalled my whole system - it works now, however it doesn't answer the question where the wrong Newtonsoft.Json.dll came from and why it didn't show up in the GAC, I can finally again work on that project.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in VS 2013 for web projects where there is a rogue Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.0 reference left over in the .csproj from the default project template that needs to be removed manually. Maybe it's that issue? I had a similar issue on a website of mine, except I had a conflicting versions warning as I also had a reference to a newer version of Newtonsoft.Json in the same project added from NuGet I had to manually unload the project and delete it to stop the warning from appearing.

Comment: no, all my project files only reference the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json (6.0.3), or no Newtonsoft.Json at all. Also you can read, that it worked on a different machine, a wrong reference in the project file should have thrown the same error on the other machine as well.

Comment: Sometimes version conflicts can not present themselves depending on which version is copied to the output directory (MSBuild picks one arbitrarily) so could just so happen to work on another machine, but if you've inspected the .csproj file's XML and it isn't there then there must be something else. I assume you did a Clean on your original machine too to ensure the bin directory was empty (which it would have been after reinstalling and on a new machine)?

Comment: I didn't just clean it - because to my experience a clean doesn't always delete everything (had already errors where a clean wasn't enough) - I deleted all bin and obj directories. I also checked in the source code (without any libraries) and checked it out at a different place, just to make sure the folder is really clean. Also the wrong DLL wasn't anywhere in my project directory, it must have been taken somewhere from the system, but I don't know from where or which one and it was impossible for me to find it out.