# The primary reference could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0"

Tags: c#, .net, json, azure, msbuild

This really isn't a question, but I'm adding it here in the hopes that it will help someone searching for a solution.

We use the RedGate SQL Comparison SDK to compare databases at run time.  About a week ago our builds stopped working with the following error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3275: The primary reference "RedGate.SQLCompare.Engine.UIProject, Version=11.1.2.54, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f465a1c156d4d57, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

The interesting part is that this worked on other machines, as well as a new Windows 10 box with VS.NET 2015.  It just wouldn't work on our build machine.

I went through a bunch of things trying to find the cause and a solution.  As it turned out, we had recently installed the Azure SDK v.2.8 on this box to test some integration points.  Going back to a "what changed" set of questions, we removed the Azure SDK v.2.8 and all projects once again built successfully.

I hope this can help someone save a bunch of hunting in the future.

Comment: Yep, it's the Azure SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25790658/474702

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio is throwing a "wrong" compile time exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922637/visual-studio-is-throwing-a-wrong-compile-time-exception)

Comment: Sharing knowledge is welcomed here and judging by the +12 votes it was useful, but please next time format it as a [question + accepted self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)